# Entity Framework 6, cannot add a new entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity framework 6.1.3 on a .Net 4.5 WCF/HTTP app. I'm having some trouble saving new data.

my code looks like this :

```
using (AgpModel model = new AgpModel())
{
    Entite.db.commentaire comment = commentaire.toDB();
    model.commentaires.Add(comment);
    model.SaveChanges();
    commentaire.Id = comment.id;
}
```

`AgpModel` is my context, `commentaire` is my front model wich can be serialized over WCF, and `comment` is the object i'm trying to save.

The `toDB()` is the method transforming `commentaire` into `comment`.

When adding my very *first* data to the table, I'm having an exception on the call of `SaveChanges()` which says :

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I tried the method available at the link below only to have this exception :

> OriginalValues cannot be used for entities in the Added state.

Reading on the table works fine.

Here is some extra code that can help you understand :

The toDB method :

```
public db.commentaire toDB()
{
    return new db.commentaire() {
        id = this.Id,
        stagiaire = this.IdStagiaire,
        utilisateur = this.IdUtilisateur,
        niveau = (int)this.Niveau,
        contenu = this.Contenu,
        date = this.Date
    };
}
```

The commentaire class :

```
[Table("agp.commentaires")]
public partial class commentaire
{
    [Key]
    [Column("commentaire", Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int utilisateur { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("date", Order = 2, TypeName = "smalldatetime")]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int stagiaire { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    [StringLength(300)]
    public string contenu { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 5)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int niveau { get; set; }

    public virtual utilisateur utilisateur1 { get; set; }

    public virtual Stagiaire Stagiaire1 { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit :**

The request passed to sql server 2008 :

```
INSERT [agp].[commentaires]([utilisateur], [date], [stagiaire], [contenu], [niveau]) VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)
SELECT [commentaire] FROM [agp].[commentaires] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [commentaire] = scope_identity() AND [utilisateur] = @0 AND [date] = @1 AND [stagiaire] = @2 AND [contenu] = @3 AND [niveau] = @4
```

with those parameters :

- @0: '1' (Type = Int32)
- @1: '30/07/2015 18:50:02' (Type = DateTime2)
- @2: '1786' (Type = Int32)
- @3: 'coucou' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 300)
- @4: '2' (Type = Int32)

Executed on my own this way and waorks ok :

```
DECLARE @0 as INT  = 1;
DECLARE @1 AS DateTime2 = '30/07/2015 18:50:02';
DECLARE @2 AS int = 1786;
DECLARE @3 AS nvarchar(300) = 'coucou';
DECLARE @4 AS int = 2;

INSERT [agp].[commentaires]([utilisateur], [date], [stagiaire], [contenu], [niveau])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)
SELECT [commentaire]
FROM [agp].[commentaires]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [commentaire] = scope_identity() AND [utilisateur] = @0 AND [date] = @1 AND [stagiaire] = @2 AND [contenu] = @3 AND [niveau] = @4
```

Still don't understand

Answer (score 1):

With your `public DateTime date { get; set; }` set to `Column(Typename="smalldatetime")` and your database appearing to expect a european date object.  Perhaps passing a generic `DateTime` to SQL is giving a `smalldatetime` that is out of bounds for the expected minimum/maximum allowable `DateTime` values.

I would suggest setting `CultureInfo enGB = new CultureInfo("en-GB");` for your session as it appears your database may be specifying a specific date format.  I would assume that Entity Framework would put the format in the format accepted in all cases:

```
YYYYMMDD
YYYY-MM-DDThh:nn:ss[.mmmmmmm]
```

However, your exception is not pointing to an exact column causing the issue.  Your composite keys are all declared properly, and your `toDB()` call appears to have populated all of the columns with data (though you'd need to set a breakpoint and validate that yourself).  The only other thing I can think of that would trigger that error is an acceptable `DateTime` being set in your model, but being converted into an SQL format that is out-of-bounds of the min/max range for `smalldatetime` due to culture difference.